# AlarmManager with WakeLock not working

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I am working on a application that would create an alarm on the screen. Every hour when I press a button. I have one class where I define the AlarmManager, WakeLock and A window that will open on fullscreen when the alarm is triggered, and I am launching it from my MainActivity.class. But I have no error and the alarm will simply not run. I am a newbie so please point me in a right direction. I have done my research but I simply cannot find what is wrong with my code.

MyAlarmReceiverActivity code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
    mWakeLock.acquire();
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.alarm);

    Button stopAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStopAlarm);
    stopAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            finish();
        }
    });
    playSound(this, getAlarmUri());
}

private void playSound(Context context, Uri alert)
{
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try
    {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, alert);
        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM)!=0)
        {
            mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
            mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
    }catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.i("AlarmReceiver","No audio files are found!");
    }
}

private Uri getAlarmUri(){
    Uri alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alert == null)
    {
        alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        if (alert == null)
        {
            alert = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        }
    }
    return alert;
}

protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    mWakeLock.release();
}
```

On my main Activity i am running it with this code

```
public void spusteniePripomienok (){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Spustil si pripomienky každých "+ interval, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmRecieverActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, 2, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT );
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(MainActivity.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: I will try it today and let u know if it helped, thanks

Comment: Sorry man didnt manage to make it work for my, ive changed the alarmreceiver for notifications. Its not better but its easy to code. Meybe the problem was simple but i dont have time to play with it :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try changing your PowerManager code to something like this to see if it works:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
mWakelock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK
            | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK
            | PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "");
mWakeLock.acquire();
```